# Set value to a hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

As you can see I am a newbie on JavaScript and I am working on a form that needs to send the today's date value when a user hits submit to know when the information was last updated.

I currently have the following code, but doesn't seem to update the date on the field. Could you please help me understand why?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  var datetoday = new Date();
  var months = new makeArray('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec');
  var day = datetoday.getDate();
  var month = datetoday.getMonth() + 1;
  var yyyy = datetoday.getFullYear();
  var my_date = day+"-"+months[month]+"-"+yyyy;

  document.getElementById("DATE_TODAY").value = my_date;
</script>
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  * First Name:
  <input name="FNAME" type="text" />
  <br>
  * Last Name:
  <input name="LNAME" type="text" />
  <br>
  * Street Address:
  <input name="ADDRESS" type="text" />
  <input type="hidden" name="DATE_TODAY" id="DATE_TODAY" />
</form>
```

Comment: it is set as a preference center, meaning that the user can go back to the form at any time, update the information and submit.
This means the value must be passed on submit to update the database with the date the update was made. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Please show the form and include the code you have a question about

Comment: The code has been included, let me know if it clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

makeArray() is a method and not an object, so instantiating it is throwing you an error (see [api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)).

Just create your array like this and it seems to do what you want it to:

`var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var m_names = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
  "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
  "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var my_date = (curr_date + "-" + m_names[curr_month] + "-" + curr_year);

document.getElementById("DATE_TODAY").value = my_date;
```

```html
<input type="text" name="DATE_TODAY" id="DATE_TODAY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: makeArray is not defined

You can use:

```
var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
```